# Undefined variable: while saving user inputted data in text fields on form submi

Tags: php, html, forms, session, variables

When error_reporting(E_ALL); is turned on I'm having the following example of notice

```
Notice:  Undefined variable: name in /home/user/public_html/directory/subdirectory/test.php on line 111
Notice:  Undefined variable: identity in /home/user/public_html/directory/subdirectory/test.php on line 116
```

in every form field if I want to save user inputted data in text fields using session after the form is submitted by the users.

Example of my current code is as following:

```
GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
GetSQLValueString($_POST['identity'], "text")

  <?php  $_SESSION['form'] = $_POST; ?>

  <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="userform" id="userform">
  <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<php$_SESSION['form']['name'] = '';?><php $_SESSION['form']['name']; ?>" size="25" />
  <input name="identity" type="text" id="identity" value="<php$_SESSION['form']['identity'] = '';?><php $_SESSION['form']['identity']; ?>" size="25" />

and so on.............
```

I gout suggestion about eliminating undefined index using

```
<php$_SESSION['form']['name'] = '';?>
```

as value of text field like,

```
 <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<php$_SESSION['form']['name'] = '';?><php $_SESSION['form']['name']; ?>" size="25" />
```

The above code resolves undefined index notice but produces undefined variable  notice.

The form works well when error reporting is off.

Any idea, how to define the undefined variable in this case?

Comment: Look at your HTML - you'll see that `<php$_SESSION['form']['name'] = '';?>` doesn't run any PHP at all.

Comment: @halfer My mistake in hurriness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This notice is raised because before the form is posted, there are no values in `$_SESSION['form']` but you try to display them. You can fix this by checking for a post
and filling `$_SESSION['form']` with an empty array if not:

```
if($_POST){
    $_SESSION['form'] = $_POST; 
}else{
    $_SESSION['form'] = array('name'=>'','identity'=>'' //etc);

}

?>


  <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="userform" id="userform">
  <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['form']['name'] ;?>" size="25" />
  <input name="identity" type="text" id="identity" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['form']['identity'];?>" size="25" />
```

Alternately you could use `isset` before echoing each variable.

Also note that you must use `echo` or `print` to actually display the values.

Comment: @webnoob Yeah, just copied the Op's html. Should have checked that - edited now

Answer (score 2):

correct it

```
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<php$_SESSION['form']['name'] = '';?><php $_SESSION['form']['name']; ?>" size="25" />
```

to

```
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['form']['name']; ?>" size="25" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of not define the variable so do one think.....!
define your session array to null

```
<?php  

$_SESSION['form'] = array(); //to define null

if(isset($_POST)){
  $_SESSION['form'] = $_POST; 
}
```

Now your your code very carefully like:_

```
<input name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['form']['name']; ?>"  />
```

Comment: No, no, no - several mistakes here. The PHP tags are not correctly opened, there is no value in _not_ echoing here (as per your first snippet), and the use of `@` is discouraged in all but a rare set of cases. That tries to hide the problem, not fix it.

Comment: @halfer you are Right MAN...!